# How to fetch and insert user's phone number in text field on visit

Tags: javascript, php, android, html, ios

Goal: When the User view page, from mobile device, automatically insert his phone number in the input field, to make it easier to convert him in a lead.

Of course there will be a privacy policy etc.

It will be a promo page, where you can get an 10% discount on Burger King if you'll leave a phone number. When it's already typed-in it's a lot easier i Think.

So, can we automatically insert mobile user's phone number in text field?

If we can, what language do we have to use.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Before start coding. Please improve your spelling mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

`Manifest`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

`Activity`

```
TelephonyManager tMgr = (TelephonyManager)mAppContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String mPhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();
```

Comment: Nice one, looks good to me. However, bear in mind that some carriers don't store the handsets' phone number on the SIM card

Comment: Thanks, what about iOS? Is it possible?

Comment: Can you please explain - where on website I have to  put in part starts with "TelephonyManager tMgr =...". Thank you

Comment: For some security reason Apple might reject the app which requests number. So, I think NOT to get is a good idea

Comment: It has to be a website, not the app =)

Comment: It will not work on all device. You have to know that.

Answer (score 0):

```
textfield.text = CTSettingCopyMyPhoneNumber();
```

but first import `CoreTelephony.framework`

Answer (score 0):

In short, it's not possible. Reason being is the same reason as to why you cannot access local files via a website. It would be a huge security and privacy issue if the browser was automatically allowed to access the local filesystem without user input.

You can ease the burden of phone number input by having masked inputs on the website in question. [This article](http://www.sitepoint.com/working-phone-numbers-javascript/) goes into quite a lot of detail regarding how to deal with telephone numbers in JavaScript. However, this is probably as close as you can get unfortunately.

Good luck!